# Show the answers with the score lower than 60% Qna Maker with azure App Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I have set up an Azure Bot with Luis and QnA Maker (in C#, Bot Framework v4). I want to query the App Insights and get information about the questions asked together with their answer, and I was able to get them, but I need to get the ones with the score lower than 60%
and I don't get the less than <=

[image]

Comment: your line 11 looks funny. You can't have a numeric operator with a "string" result. Try changing the 60 to .6

Answer (score 0):

You should use [toint()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/tointfunction) operator to convert `string` to `int` type, then use <= operator. **In line 11 of your query**, change it like below:

```
where toint(score) <= 60 and message ="xxxxx"
```

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please accept it as answer as per this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top). Thanks.